# Prism Shared Viewmodel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

- Platform: Xamarin forms
- Prism version: 6.3.0
- Xamarin version (if applicable): 2.3.4

hello I'm using prism. I have a `Tabbedpage` how can i share a single viewmodel for all daughters views?

my xaml:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
          xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MySednaApp.Views;assembly=MySednaApp"
          xmlns:view="clr-namespace:MySednaApp.View;assembly=MySednaApp"
          prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
          x:Class="MySednaApp.Views.PubblicaArticoliTabbedPage"
          Title="{view:Translate PubblicaArticoli}" 
  <TabbedPage.ToolbarItems 
      <ToolbarItem x:Name="Delete2" Icon="ico_delete.png" Text="Elimina"    Command="{Binding delete}"    
          <ToolbarItem.Order 
              <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ToolbarItemOrder" 
                  <On Platform="iOS" Primary</On 
                  <On Platform="Android" Secondary</On 
              </OnPlatform 
          </ToolbarItem.Order 
      </ToolbarItem 
      <ToolbarItem x:Name="Save" Icon="ico_save.png"  Command="{Binding save}"  Order="Primary" Priority="0" / 
  </TabbedPage.ToolbarItems 
  <views:PubblicaArticoliDettaglioPage x:Name="pubblicaArticoliDettaglioPage"/ 
  <views:PubblicaArticoliGaugePage  x:Name="pubblicaArticoliGaugePage"/ 
  <views:PubblicaArticoliFotoPage  x:Name="pubblicaArticoliFotoPage"/ 
</TabbedPage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, just set the BindingContext of each of your tabs to the TabbedPage's BindingContext in your code-behind.

Comment: Thank you for rhe reply, How do I get the tabbedpage's bindingcontext from the children's behind?

Comment: You gave each page a name, so use the name to access them `pubblicaArticoliDettaglioPage.BindingContext = this.BindingContext`

Comment: thanks, this works.
but if I want to share the same viewmodel between different pages that are not tabbedpage? how could I do. can not use a viewmodellocator resolve?

Comment: You could consider creating  a base clase will all your functionality and create different VMs that inherit from it, this way you'd use the default VM locator,  I know it's not exactly what you want...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these properties in the XAML page to bind the viewmodel

```
xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
```

Comment: but I want to assign the same instance of a viewmodel to all children